# Como fazer um select dependendo de algumas condições que vem por parametros no laravel 4.2?

Tags: mysql, laravel-eloquent

Meu problema é o seguinte....

Eu tenho uma rota que recebe o ano e mês para buscar algumas informaçoes no banco.

Quando não vier o mês eu preciso que seja feita a soma de todos os meses do ano solicitado.

```
if($month == 0){
    $dbRegister = DB::table('tb_data')->select(DB::raw("SUM(tb_data.total_points) as total_points"));
}else{
     $dbRegister = DB::table('tb_data')->select('tb_data.total_points');
}

$dbRegister->select(DB::raw('tb_data.user)....
```

Se eu deixo o select separado dessa forma ele não funciona. Alguem saberia me dizer?

Obrigada :D

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer varios selects separados com o laravel 4.2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272080/como-fazer-varios-selects-separados-com-o-laravel-4-2)