# Como fazer varios selects separados com o laravel 4.2?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Olá eu preciso fazer um select em uma tabela, porem se eu não receber o mês pelo parametro devo fazer o metodo SUM para somar todos os mêses

```
if($month != 0){
            $dbRegister = tb_data::selectRaw('tb_data.total_points');
        }else{
            $dbRegister = tb_data::selectRaw('sum(tb_data.total_points)');
        }   
$dbRegister->selectRaw('TB_USERS.login,TB_USERS.name)->get()
```

O problema é que se eu faço dessa forma acima, o laravel dsconsidera o select dentro do if

Alguem teria uma solução melhor?

Comment: 1 . Qual valor está vindo em $month ??  2. Pelo que você diz: "receber o mês pelo parâmetro" você poderia utilizar a função isset() para verificar isso, tente fazer um teste e veja se funciona.

Comment: Olá. O que acabou resolvendo o meu problema foi a soluçao descrita abaixo, mas mesmo assim obrigada

Comment: Laiane se resolveu o seu problema aceite como resposta da sua pergunta!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o [addSelect](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects) da seguinte forma:

```
if($month != 0)
{
      $dbRegister = tb_data::selectRaw('tb_data.total_points');
}
else
{
     $dbRegister = tb_data::selectRaw('sum(tb_data.total_points)');
}   


$dbRegister->addSelect('TB_USERS.login','TB_USERS.name')->get();
```

Ou seja, o `addSelect` adiciona mais elementos na `SQL`.

<sub>**Referencia:** [Query Builder - Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects)</sub>